# What possibilities do I have if I want to send mail from Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, smtp, sendmail, imap

My intention is to be able to send mail from Windows Server 2008. What possibilities do I have? SMTP client, SENDMAIL etc.? What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: What is the source of the email? Scripts, web pages, an application?

Comment: Sciprts, mainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Included SMTP Service is fully capable of SENDING emails. Nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

www.blat.net - very flexible and widely used.